# Firebase unlink not works well

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm doing a record with multiple providers (password and Facebook). When I connect it work. But when I disconnect one of them, in the console is modified Firebase well but in my application it is still connected:

```
if (mAuth.getCurrentUser().getProviderData().size()<3) {  // Si solo hay 2 (Firebase y otro) no hemos hecho link
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        numProvs = 0;
    }
    else {
        mAuth.getCurrentUser().unlink(proveedor).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "unlink: " + proveedor);
                numProvs--;
                if (!task.isSuccessful())
                    showErrorDialog(task.getException().getMessage());
                mAuthProgressDialog.hide();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Example:
If I am connected to Password and Facebook (good and Firebase user who is always) when I want to disconnect from one of the two, I enter the else (having two suppliers the default Firebase and other it would enter if and disconnect the user because it would be the last supplier) and there do the unlink. the unlink

It works well in Firebase Auth within the console but if I check onComplete providers is like me but I had logged out (when the console is no longer the provider).

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/XmOZ5zADGA4

Comment: I already works well, something must have been done in Firebase because I have not touched anything

Comment: Good to hear. I'm not aware of changes on our side, but may have missed something.